# Gente, estou com uma dúvida com MySQL sobre Procedures. É possível eu guardar o retorno delas em uma variável do BD?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysqli, mysql, stored-procedures

Estou com um processo repetitivo no BD que é validar o usuário a cada solicitação, por isso, decidi criar uma procedure para isso e chamar dentro das outros quando for preciso. No entanto estou com a necessidade de dessa vez guardar o retorno da procedure. Mas não consigo alocar o valor para alguma variável de jeito nenhum. Tentei até colocar num if e não deu certo. Eu não manjo muito de back, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getmnhsInfo`(in tokn text)
foo:BEGIN
    set @verific = verificaToken(tokn);
    if (@verific is null) then
        select tokn; -- para testar o retorno, a procedure está incompleta
    end if;
    select @verific;  -- para testar o retorno, a procedure está incompleta
END
```

E a mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION wmp_fut.verificaToken does not exist -- Se eu não coloco call, ele entende como uma função
```

Observação: se eu coloco 'call' na frente ele nem salva com uma variável junto. Ele chama a procedure, executa ela, mas não aceita alocar o retorno para uma variável.

Comment: Será que você não quer criar uma `FUNCTION` e não uma `PROCEDURE`?

Comment: Exatamente! Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente, vou deixar a pergunta caso alguém precise mas, resolvi passando a procedure para função. Aí a função sim, posso alocar o retorno da forma que eu quiser.